# JQuery datetime picker automatically change my date and add space after the date input

Tags: jquery, timepicker

When I type `"2014-05-1"` in the text field which bind with a jQuery datetimepicker, it changes to `"2014-05-01"` instantly, and actually I may want to type `"2014-05-12"`.

So how can I disable this function. Thanks.

```
$("#time_input").datetimepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "../calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
  timeFormat: ""
});
```

Comment: changing `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` to `dateFormat: "yy-mm-d",` will remove the leading `0` but still allow you to enter two-digit numbers

Comment: just tried, but no luck. If I changed to dateFormat: "yy-mm-d", then when I type "2014-05-1", it will instantly changed to "2014-05-1 " (add a space after 'd').

Comment: That would probably be because you are using a `datetimepicker` instead of just a `datepicker` (since you are removing the time manually) the datetimepicker is adding a space because it expects there to be a time after the inputted date. [look at this demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for an example. Which jQuery plugin/library are you using for the `datetimepicker`? no doubt they will have a `datepicker` equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source you provided seems to be defeating the point of a `dateTimePicker` as you are manually removing the time component.

Once a date is selected the `datetimepicker` will try to format whatever is inputed into something that follows the format of "yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" (note the space between date and time) 
when you say `timeFormat: ""` all you are doing is emptying the `hh:mm:ss` of the above, but the datetime formatting keeps the space after the date. (it doesn't know you don't want it)

From the looks of it what you are actually after is a [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Code-wise it is pretty much exactly the same:

```
$("#time_input").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "../calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-d"
});
```

the two differences are we are calling a `.datepicker` and changing the `dateFormat` to `yy-mm-d` [according to the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) a single `d` will:

> d - day of month (no leading zero)

Hope that helps